# How to generate a range of number from two number (a,b) via user input

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do I generate a range of number from user input of (a,b) in a list,
such that if a user input (1, 10) into a list [1, 10] then using range function to generate a range of (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)into a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] ?

and also

how do I print all the values in a list horizontally in a single line? 
E.g. The leap years are a, b, c

My codes below, it will show three different lines instead of 1.
The leap years are a
The leap years are b
The leap years are c

MY CODES:

```
try:
input_string = str(raw_input("Enter the leap year range: "))
number_list = input_string.split(",")
number_list = [int(num) for num in number_list]
number_list.sort()
yearHigh = max(number_list)
yearLow = min(number_list)

#print ("Here is a list of leap years between " + str(yearLow) + " and " + str(yearHigh)  + ":")
while yearLow <= yearHigh:
    if yearLow % 100 == 0 and yearLow % 400 == 0 or yearLow % 4 == 0 and yearLow % 100 != 0:
        leapYear = []
        leapYear.append(yearLow)
        yearLow += 1
        print ("the leap years are: "), leapYear
    else:
        yearLow += 1
except:
    print ("Please enter a valid year!")
```

Comment: Without reading the code, `range(int(input('Enter a number: ')))` does that help? That way they'll only need to enter `10` and you'll get the `1` to `10`.

Comment: `raw_input` *already* returns a `str` value; there's no need to call `str` explicitly. Also, please consider switching to Python 3.

Comment: For information Python 2 is end of life in just a few months.